# Java - How to ensure visibility of array returned by a Callable thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to calculate an array via a thread like this:

```
public class Calculator implements Callable<int[]> {
    @Override
    public int[] call() {
        int[] result = new int[100];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i]++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And a main thread may look like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
Future<int[]> future = executor.submit(new Calculator());
int[] result = future.get();
```

I cannot figure out how to ensure the visibility of all elements in `result`. According to the [Memory Consistency Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) section, there seems to be no such happens-before relation.

One way to walk around is to wrap the array into an `AtomicIntegerArray`. But I wonder whether there is some other solution which can be generalized to any kind of primitive arrays.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the javadoc of Future https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

> Memory consistency effects: Actions taken by the asynchronous computation happen-before actions following the corresponding Future.get() in another thread.

Comment: It's also on the page (package description) linked by OP.